# Limit search results to WooCommerce Products only in frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce, product

**Background:**

I would like to limit the search results to show only WooCommerce Products. This code below does exactly what I want.

```
//Only show products in the front-end search results
function lw_search_filter_pages($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
        $query->set( 'wc_query', 'product_query' );
    }
    return $query;
}
 
add_filter('pre_get_posts','lw_search_filter_pages');
```

**Problem:**

By using the code above, it affects how some of the plugins on my site work. For example, in Elementor Pro, when I am searching for the `Checkout Page`, it will not show up. Instead, only `Products` show up. Example screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `! is_admin()` will limit this filter to frontend only to avoid many problems on backend:

```
// Only show products in the front-end search results
add_filter('pre_get_posts','lw_search_filter_pages');
function lw_search_filter_pages($query) {
    // Frontend search only
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_search() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'product');
        $query->set( 'wc_query', 'product_query' );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to write Wordpress code the way you do. Do you have any good courses to recommend me? Thanks.

Comment: I just started to learn few years ago for clients trying to solve and understand little things by little things… and on StackOverflow real cases questions where I was trying to answer myself, understand, analyze other people code… Now I just code only for WooCommerce.

Comment: Is it possible to limit the search results to only articles(blog), products and category "comedy"?

Comment: Can these results be displayed on the search results page in, for example, three separate sections? (Products, Blog and Comedy category)

Comment: My answer here was just adding `! is_admin()` in the if statement, to avoid problems in the backend. Here in this code, the search if for 'product' post type and WooCommerce product query. I am only good on WooCommerce related questions. I suppose that is possible using pre_get_post hook to limit the search on blog posts,  product or comedy category.